# How to Deselect Radio Chips?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, radio-buttons, deselection

I have a number of statuses from which a user can select only one status. I tried this new control which is sort of an alternative to radio to buttons where user can select their desired status by just clicking on the pill and the rest will deselect themselves.

**Question**

> Now according to our business requirement, it is not necessary for the
>   user to specify the status. They can leave this filter blank as well
>   because their are a lot of other filters which can be used as well.

For that I want to provide an option of deselecting a pill. The options that I have:

1. Click on the selected pill to deselect it
2. Provide a deselect button at the end in order to deselect your choice

Which one will serve the purpose? I'm also open to new solutions.

*Here is the gif for the status filter area*

[image]

Comment: My gut feeling would be to have a pill named "none" rather than a "deselect" button.

Answer (score 1):

Place both. 
Deselect button if there should be different in design from rest of the pills. 
Clicking the pill to deselect it should be anyhow there, it is the standard behaviour. I would play with shadows or elevation to make more clear. So pressed should be with inset shadow / stamp effect, also on hover you animate it so its clear it will be "pressed" / selected.